# Scaling animation in CSS don't work

Tags: html, css

I have problem to make my animation works. I am trying to scale some object but nothing hapens. I looked many similar answers on stackoverflow, but nothing helped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style> 
    .logo {
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

    width:60%; 
    height:300px;

   -webkit-animation-name: example; 
   -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 

    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);}
    10% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    }


    @keyframes example {
    0% {transform: scale(1,1);}
    10% {transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    100% {transform: scale(1,1);}
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="logo" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried in every major browser, but nowhere works.
Hope someone will see error, or give some other suggestion.

Comment: You are missing `-` in the prefixed versions of the `keyframes`, `transform` and you are probably using a older version of Chrome. Adding the required `-`s make it work perfectly.

Comment: I think you have to add the property animation-timing-function

Comment: @Harry , didnt helped :( , and i didnt used only Chrome, I tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some unclosed braces in there.

EG: this line

```
 10% {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
```

---

```css
 .logo {
   margin: auto;
   background-color: black;
   width: 60%;
   height: 300px;
   -webkit-animation-name: example;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-name: example;
   animation-duration: 4s;
 }
 @webkit-keyframes example {
   0% {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
   }
   10% {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
   }
   100% {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
   }
 }
 @keyframes example {
   0% {
     transform: scale(1, 1);
   }
   10% {
     transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
   }
   100% {
     transform: scale(1, 1);
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: I really need to find eye doctor. Thanx